# Segmentation fault at if statement using Linux Ncurses

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses

My code works fine till the line 27 (`if(answer == answer2)`), when it gets there program crashes and it writes 'segmentation fault' in my terminal.

It should be working, because if statement compares two strings and if these strings are the same, it does one action, if they aren't it does another action, but don't know why it doesn't work.

I'm a beginner programmer.

Here's code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ncurses.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {
        char persentage = '%';
        initscr();
        curs_set(0);
        string answer;
        string answer2;
        int tipi,tipi2;

        move(8,0);
        printw("Enter the phenotype of parent 1: ");
        curs_set(1);
        scanw("%s",&answer);
        curs_set(0);
        move(9,0);
        printw("Is the phenotype fully dominant(AA) or partly(Aa)? (type '1' for AA, '2' for Aa): ");
        curs_set(1);
        scanw("%d",&tipi); 
        curs_set(0);
        move(11,0);
        printw("Enter the phenotype of parent 2: ");
        curs_set(1);
        scanw("%s",&answer2);
        curs_set(0);
        if(answer == answer2) {
            move(12,0);
            printw("Is the phenotype of parent 2 fully dominant(AA) or partly(Aa)? (type '1' for AA, '2' for Aa): ");
            curs_set(1);
            scanw("%d",&tipi2);
            curs_set(0);
            if (tipi == 1 && tipi2 == 1) {
                move(15,0);
                printw("Persentage of a child's phenotype to be %s is 100%c",answer,persentage);
                }
            if (tipi == 1 && tipi2 == 2) {
                move(15,0);
                printw("Persentage of a child's phenotype to be %s is 100%c",answer,persentage);
            }
            if (tipi == 2 && tipi2 == 1) {
                move(15,0);
                printw("Persentage of a child's phenotype to be %s is 100%c",answer,persentage);
                }
            if (tipi == 2 && tipi2 == 2) {
                move(15,0);
                printw("Persentage of a child's phenotype to be %s is 75%c",answer,persentage);
                move(16,0);
                printw("Persentage of a child's phenotype to be recessive phenotype is 25%c",persentage);
                }
        }
        else {

            if (tipi == 1) {
                move(13,0);
                printw("Persentage of a child's phenotype to be %s is 75%c",answer,persentage);
                move(14,0);
                printw("Persentage of a child's phenotype to be %s is 25%c",answer2,persentage);
            }
            if (tipi == 2) {
                move(13,0);
                printw("Persentage of a child's phenotype to be %s is 50%c",answer,persentage);
                move(14,0);
                printw("Persentage of a child's phenotype to be %s is 50%c",answer2,persentage);
            }       

    }
}       


    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Do you have warnings enabled? You compiled should have complained about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`answer` and `answer2` are C++ `std::string` objects. You can't use them as arguments to any `scanf`-like function. That will lead to *undefined behavior* as the `"%s"` format expects a pointer to a `char`, i.e. a `char*`. Your compiler *should* have shouted warnings to you about this.

If you want to use the C++ `std::string` object, then one solution is that you [*resize*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) them to some maximum length, then get a pointer to the *first character* in the string (e.g. `&answer[0]`).

Another solution is to use temporary arrays of `char` as destination, and you then initialize the `std::string` objects to those C-style strings.

---

While there's really no explanation needed for [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) except that it makes your program *ill-formed* and invalid, here's a short explanation about what happens here.

When you use e.g. `&answer` as the destination in a `scanw` function call, it uses the pointer to the string object as the `char*`, and will overwrite internal data inside the `answer` object. That internal data usually is a pointer to the actual string, and the size of the string. When this data is overwritten, the pointer will no longer be what is expected, and it will point to some memory location that might not be available to your process. That will lead to a crash when attempting to dereference the pointer (which is done in the comparison).

Comment: but what if I want to have an input of size of 2 or few words? what should i do, can u write exactly how to solve my code in this case ? I just want to have two inputs of max 2 words each(answer,answer2) and want my if statement to compare them. How is it possible ?